# What does "<>" symbol mean?

Tags: sql

I read the Laravel manual and found this symbol in the code below:

```
select * from users where name = 'John' or (votes > 100 and title <> 'Admin')
```

So what dose "<>" mean??

Comment: Yes, not equal.  Think about it as `<` less than or `>` greater than.  In other words, no equivalency.

Comment: This is not a PHP or Laravel question, but an SQL one.

Comment: `a <> b` is a *standard* SQL not-equals comparison - but only for *non-NULL* values. Some DB's support `!=`, often in a 'legacy mode'. These basic questions will be covered in basic tutorials.

Comment: @lean Most likely because this would have been answered in any basic SQL tutorial. It's not about not having the question on SO. There probably isn't a question about operator < either, but doesn't make it "right" to ask one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both <> and != are OK I think!

Answer (score 2):

It means "not equal to" in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

**Both != and <> has same Properties IN SQL:**

**!= :**
Checks if the values of two operands are equal or not, if values are not equal then condition becomes true.

```
(a != b) is true.
```

**<>:**

Checks if the values of two operands are equal or not, if values are not equal then condition becomes true.

```
(a <> b) is true.
```

Comment: Depends on dbms. <> is ANSI SQL. != is supported by some products, other odd alternatives are /= and ^= .